# Reference userform data in excel vba sql statements?

Tags: sql, forms, vba, excel

I'm trying to reference userform data in SQL queries in excel 2010. When running the following code as my form submit action, I get an error that one or more parameters have not been provided in the SQL query.

```
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()

    Dim Connection As ADODB.Connection
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=I:\DB.xlsx; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES"";"

    Dim SQL As String

'Transfer information
SQL = "INSERT INTO [Tests$]" & _
"(PartNo, RootCause, CorrectiveAction, AssignedTo, Verification, Comments, DateOpened, DateClosed, " & _
"Status, Purpose, ProdDate, ShipDate, TestDate, SampleDate, CusName, Facility, Result, Wire, StartingDia, " & _
"WireType, IncomingDia, FailMode, RootCauseDetail)" & _
"VALUES" & _
"([Forms][frmTesting]![PartNo], [Forms][frmTesting]![RCause], [Forms][frmTesting]![Corrective], " & _
"[Forms][frmTesting]![Assigned], [Forms][frmTesting]![Verification], [Forms][frmTesting]![Comments], " & _
"[Forms][frmTesting]![OpenDate], [Forms][frmTesting]![CloseDate], [Forms][frmTesting]![Status], " & _
"[Forms][frmTesting]![Purpose], [Forms][frmTesting]![ProdDate], [Forms][frmTesting]![ShipDate], " & _
"[Forms][frmTesting]![TestDate], [Forms][frmTesting]![SampleDate], [Forms][frmTesting]![Customer], [Forms][frmTesting]![Facility], " & _
"[Forms][frmTesting]![Result], [Forms][frmTesting]![Wire], [Forms][frmTesting]![StartingDia], " & _
"[Forms][frmTesting]![WireType], [Forms][frmTesting]![IncomingDia], [Forms][frmTesting]![FailMode], [Forms][frmTesting]![RCDetail])"

    Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
    Call Connection.Open(ConnectionString)

    Call Connection.Execute(SQL, , CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText Or ExecuteOptionEnum.adExecuteNoRecords)
    Connection.Close
    Set Connection = Nothing


End Sub
```

Am I using the correct form object reference syntax for SQL queries? Is there a difference between Excel and Access with how to reference form data?

Comment: Typo: This [Forms][frmTesting]![PartNo] is actually [Forms]![frmTesting]![Partno] for all form references in the block.

Comment: You can [edit] your post to fix that, instead of fixing-in-the-comments ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In case any viewers run across the same issue and are interested. I found the easiest solution to be something like SQL = "INSERT INTO [Tests$] (PartNo) Values ('" & frmTesting.PartNo & "')"